# How to prepare Layout of one activity from another?

Tags: android

Lets say that i am having main activity as

```
public class home_activity extends ActionBarActivity {
    EditText t1;
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.home_layout);
        t1=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.status);
        t1.setText("single");
    }
}
```

Now i have another activity that contain radio group. In that radio group contains 3 radio button single, married,divorce. If there is change using   in radio group the t1 should be changed.The second activity as follow.

```
public class another_activity extends ActionBarActivity {
    RadioGroup g1;
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.another_layout);
        g1=(RadioGroup)findViewById(R.id.radiogroup);
        g1.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new RadioGroup.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(RadioGroup group, int checkedId) {
                //here what should i do to get result when user checks married or divorce radio button in another activity
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use Preferences(Google it up) to store the marital status from your another_activity and load it from the preferences and display it on textView of the main Activity.

Incase the flow of your application is something like this,

```
Home_activty -> Another_Activity (after the user makes the status seclection),
you return back to the home_Activity (i.e)
Another_Activity ->Home_Activity
```

Then the solution is to start another_activity for result by the method

`startAcitivtyForResult();`

Reference: [How to manage `startActivityForResult` on Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10407159/how-to-manage-start-activity-for-result-on-android)

http://developer.android.com/training/basics/intents/result.html